# Inverse Laplace for a something in sin form but with an addition power of two on the bottom

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplace-method, inverse-laplace

I have a question asking to solve the following with Laplace transformations. I get through most of it, but I'm stumped in the final stage.

$$y''+4y'+29y=e^{-2t}\sin(5t),\quad \ y(0)=5,\ y'(0)=-2.$$

I run through the whole thing until I end up here.

$$(s^2+4s+29)Y=5s+3+\frac{5}{(s+2)^2+25}$$

I can divide and solve for the $5s+3$ bit fine, but the issue is that the part in the very right, the Laplace transformation of $e^{-2t}\sin(5t)$, gains a power of two on the bottom, as $s^2+4s+29$ becomes $(s+2)^2+25$. I have no idea how to inverse Laplace from that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$ \mathcal{L}\{t\sin at \}(s) = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{\sin at\}(s) = -\frac{d}{ds} \left( \frac{a}{s^2+a^2} \right) = \frac{2as}{(s^2 + a^2)^2} $$

$$ \mathcal{L}\{t\cos at\}(s) = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{\cos at\}(s) = -
\frac{d}{ds} \left( \frac{s}{s^2+a^2} \right) = \frac{s^2 - a^2}{(s^2 + a^2)^2} $$

This suggests a partial fraction decomposition of the form

$$ \frac{(5s+3)\big((s+2)^2 + 25\big) + 5}{\big((s+2)^2 + 25\big)^2} = 
A\frac{s+2}{(s+2)^2 + 25} + B\frac{5}{(s+2)^2 + 25} + \\
C\frac{(s+2)^2-25}{\big((s+2)^2+25\big)} + D\frac{10(s+2)}{\big((s+2)^2 + 25\big)^2} $$

For sanity, I suggest writing $u=s+2$